# Is Android's touch and click event controllable?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, gesture-recognition

I am trying to work on a gesture controlled app which could let the user interact with someone's device(all apps in the device and basic activities) with gesture, running the app in the background and capturing camera footage. Is it possible? If yes what are the tools I need to use?
If this isn’t possible, is there any other way to achieve this kind of goal in Android?

Comment: `let the user interact with someone's device with gesture` Not sure what you are asking. That's how android interactions works, with gestures.

Comment: Which part is problematic? Injecting input events (have you read https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/input) ?

Comment: Maybe the above doc is what I am looking for. So to clear myself again, I want to make an App that a disabled person can use to use the device(from playing music, to make phone call, I mean not only to interact with my app, including all apps from opening to closing) using facial expression and movements. You can also share any other resourses that might be helpful for me (without the processing part).